# Detect squid proxy local network

Tags: proxy, squid, http-proxy

I setup squid on a OS X server machine for caching, but I don't see much improvement.

I'm trying to check if this is actually working, should I be happy enough that internet is working when squid is running and not when turn off ? Or there is other tool to check the proxy ?

When I trace route something I see the IP of my router but not my server, is that normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my main goal of using a caching proxy was to save buffering on Youtube video (kids are really demanding...) but after research, I figured out that dynamic catching like youtube was not possible, or really hard to implement.